# Azure devops rest API postman error Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: TestPointUpdateParams

Tags: azure, rest, postman, azure-devops-rest-api

Hello I'm trying to update the outcome of a test point with the azure devops rest api using postman from **active** to **passed**

This is the request i'm using:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/fodservices/Training%20projects/_apis/testplan/Plans/70152/Suites/70154/TestPoint?api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

And this is the body

```
{
    "value" : [
    {
            "id": 11431,
            "isActive": false,
            "results": {
                
                "outcome": "passed"
            }
    }
]
}
```

I'm getting a 400 bad request error and the message is : **Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: TestPointUpdateParams**
Anyone can help what I'm doing wrong please

[image: postman error]

Comment: Have you referred to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/test-point-update-v60-preview-value-cannot-be-null/911841?viewtype=all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, we need to update the request body as the following json. For more details, please refer to [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/test-point-update-v60-preview-value-cannot-be-null/911841#T-N911842)

```
[
    {
            "id": 1,
            "results": {              
                  "outcome": "passed"
            }         
    }
]
```

For example

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/points/{pointIds}?api-version=6.0

[
    {
            "id": 1,
            "results": {              
                  "outcome": "passed"
            }         
    }
]
```

[image]